# How to build Java project using IntlliJ IDE instead of via shell?

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

I cloned a [GitHub rep](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle)o onto my disk an successfully built the project by:

```
ant clean-all resolve create-dot-classpath
```

within the projects root directory.

I assume this should also be possible from IntelliJ IDE but that fails by doing nothing at all - it simply states "All files are up-to-date" ... what I do is:

- "Make module 'pentaho-kettle'"
- "Compile module 'pentaho-kettle'"

I could use a hint where to look for a solution or what configuration is most likely missing.

Comment: Their README indicates that the project maintainers use Eclipse. Your best bet is probably to follow the instructions in the README to generate Eclipse project files, and to the import these eclipse projects into IntelliJ.

Comment: The problem is I work on Ubuntu and neither Eclipse nor Netbeans I so far managed to set up reliably. The IntelliJ IDE community edition otoh works like a charm.

Comment: And? How does that prevent you from importing eclipse projects generated by Ant into IntelliJ. Ant generates the eclipse .project files. Then you import them in IntelliJ. No need to have eclipse or Netbeans installed to do that.

Comment: Ahaa ... interesting! You have to know I am a total Java newbie!

Comment: But actually - that (import as Eclipse project) is what I did now that I remember it. It doesn't seem to do the trick in this case

Answer (score 1):

As the project is a multi module project based on *Ant* and *Ivy*, you have to

- import the project from sources
- configure modules (like core, ui, the plugins, …) with the right directories for main and test sources and resources (they seem to overlap with java sources in that project)
- setup the class path using an *Ivy* plugin (I recommend *IvyIDEA*), use the context menu on the `ivy.xml` file

and have luck to build. It will be some try and error!

You may also have a try importing from *Eclipse* as those `.project` and `.classpath` files are checked in. But than you also have to check the module directories, the import is more a partial guess and I worry that *IntelliJ* will not get any information about *Ivy* from the *Eclipse* setup.